# Add index of multiple arrays together

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add the values of multiple arrays at each index.
Eg.

```
arr1 = [100, 110, 121]
arr2 = [20, 25, 27.5]

newArr = [120, 135, 148.5]
```

My current approach is below.
I am finding the percentage change between stocks each day (Day 1, Day 2, Day 3 etc)

Then I am moving to the next stock and  I want to add the percentage change of stock 1 and stock 2 together. ie Append the new percentage change to the old percentage change.

What I am trying to do know is check if the index exists as a key in the object, and if it does, add the diff figure to this index.

If the index doesn't exist I want to just add the diff figure.

It is working when the index doesn't exist but when the index does exist (ie. The second, third stock etc) the old value for that index is just overwritten with the newer value.

I want to add them together.

Is there a simple clean solution for this?

[image]

```
accumPercent = {}

const portfolio = props.test.map((item) => {
        let oldPrice = item.res.data.o[0]
        item.res.data.o.map((item1, index) => {
            let diff = ((item.res.data.c[index] - oldPrice) / oldPrice) * 100
            oldPrice = item.res.data.c[index]

            if (index in Object.keys(accumPercent)) {
                accumPercent[index] = accumPercent[index] + diff
            } else {
                accumPercent[index] = diff
            }

        })
    })
```

```
    let example = [
        {
            o: [10, 20, 30]
        },


        {
            o: [10, 40, 60]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: do you have some data and the wanted result? btw, the first addition looks wrong.

Comment: what is the wanted result of all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map like this:

```js
const arr1 = [100, 110, 121]
const arr2 = [20, 25, 27.5]

const newArr = arr1.map((i, idx) => i + arr2[idx])
// result: [120, 135, 148.5]
```

---

Or if the arrays are in an object:

```js
const test = {arr1: [100, 110, 121], arr2: [20, 25, 27.5]}

const newArr = test.arr1.map((i, idx) => i + test.arr2[idx])
// result: [120, 135, 148.5]
```

Comment: The arrays are part of two different objects, would this still work?

Comment: ```test = [
  {
    o : [10, 20, 30]
  },
  
  
  {
    o : [10, 40 ,60]
  }
]```

Comment: Yes - I will update the answer with an example of that

Comment: And what if they were in seperate objects? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes.. Just use the correct object reference in place of "test" here: `test.arr2[idx]`

Comment: @LeePriestEU did this answer your question? If it did please can you mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

One more way :

```
  let fr = []
     
    arr1.forEach((d,index)=>{
      fr.push(d + arr2[index])
    })
    console.log(fr)
```